# How do I configure Vue to be able to import typescript files from Single File Components?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack, typescript-eslint

I'm developing a project with Vue.js 2 (via vue-cli 3) that has several Vue Single File Components. The project has dozens of modules already coded.

I was trying to improve the code readability and tried to add Typescript to the project by installing the vue typescript plugin (vue add typescript), and to my surprise it edited half of the files, threw a bunch of errors and broke some modules and dependencies. After that I had to revert to a point before that since the project became unusable.

I then tried to import a ts file by adding a typescript loader/parser to the webpack/eslint/babel stack, but to no avail.

So the question is, how can I import a .ts file from a component without breaking the whole thing? Is it possible at all? Of course the main point is to avoid compiling the ts into js everytime I make changes.

Edit: just to make myself clear, I need to import a .ts file into my normal Vue Component. I'm yet to find anything about that in the docs.

**Example:**

```
<script>
// The following import would look for a @/path/to/MyTSClass.js and fail

// If I added the .ts extension it would throw an 'Unexpected token' error and tell me 
// to install an 'additional loader to handle the result of these loaders'

import MyTSClass from "@/path/to/MyTSClass"; 

export default {
    name:"MyComponent",
    methods: {
        myMethod() {
            let myVar = new MyTSClass();
            return myVar.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html

Comment: Thanks for commenting. The documentation shows how to work with typescript inside the Vue components, which I don't have an interest in. I need to simply import a ts file into my normal vue setup. Also the docs require me to install vue's typescript plugin, which completely breaks my project.

Comment: @Victor Did you ever find out how to do this?

Comment: Victor & @vab2048, did yours ever find an answers, I broken my project too.